# Como retornar uma mensagem customizade na validação do Angular

Tags: angular, angular-6, validator, validation

No meu Form, eu estou usando formBuilder e eu gostaria de retornar uma mensagem customizada, como devo fazer?

```
this.Form = this.formBuilder.group({     
  name: ['', [Validators.required]]
});
```

E embaixo do input ele retorna

```
The field is required
```

Mas eu gostaria que retornasse o nome do input, algo assim

```
The field name is required
```

Se alguem puder me ajudar, estou usando Angular v14.

Answer (score 1):

existem várias abordagens para essa situação.

Em uma delas, você pode colocar em um span, e condicionar a aparecer a mensagem, seria algo do tipo

```
<span *ngIf="form.get('name').hasError('required')"> The field name is required </span>
```

Dai você pode customizar seu span com alguma classe.